Implications of injectivity of smooth maps between smooth manifolds
First of all, sorry if the title is a bit rubbish. I'm not really sure how to phrase this and any title suggestions are more than welcome.
I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding a proof from my course. Here it is below:
Let $f:M \to M'$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds of dimensions n and m respectively. Suppose $p \in M$ and the differential at p $(f_{*})_{p}:T_{p}(M) \to T_{f(p)}(M')$ is injective, then there exist local coordinates $(x_{1},...,x_{n})$, $(y_{1},...y_{m})$ in neighbourhoods $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $f(p)$ such that: $y_{i}(f(q)) = x_{i}(q)$, $\forall q \in U$ and $1 \le i \le n$.
Proof:
Let us first assume that $(f_{*})_{p}$ is injective and let $(y_{1},...y_{m})$ be a system of local coordinates around $q=f(p)$ on $M'$. We claim that it's possible to choose from a set of functions $y_{1} \circ f,...,y_{m} \circ f $ a subset of n functions that form a system of local coordinates in at $p \in M$.
Indeed, in terms of some local coordinates $w_{1},...w_{n}$ at $p$, we can write the component functions $y_{i} \circ f = f_{i}(w_{1},...w_{n})$. The hypothesis that $(f_{*})_{p}$ is injective means the matrix $\left( \frac{\partial f_{i} }{\partial w_{j}}(p) \right)_{\substack{
0 \le i \le m \\
0 \le j \le n\\
}}$
has rank n, we can thus select n indicies $i_{1},...,i_{n}$ from the set {1,...,m} such that the sub-matrix
$\left( \frac{\partial f_{i_{k}} }{\partial w_{j}}(p) \right)_{\substack{
0 \le k \le n \\
0 \le j \le n\\
}}$ gives a sqaure invertible matrix with non-zero determinant.
Then, the inverse function theorem states that $y_{i_{1}}\circ f,...,y_{i_{n}}\circ f$ give a local diffeomorphism, hence can be used as local coordinates $x_{1} = y_{i_{1}}\circ f,...,x_{n} = y_{i_{n}}\circ f,$ as required after reordering.
I'm slighly confused in the bit between the first and second paragraph of the proof, how can some local coordinates $w_{1},...w_{n}$ at $p$ be found such that, we can write the component functions $y_{i} \circ f = f_{i}(w_{1},...w_{n})$? I'd really appreciate if anyone could explain this to me since I've looked at this quite a few times and tried to google it but not really gotten anywhere really.
The full notes can be downloaded through this link and this statement is proposition 3.5) a) on pages 16-17.
Alternatively, if you don't want to click the link you can search "Christian Boehning LECTURE NOTES FOR MA3H5 MANIFOLDS Manifolds" and the notes should be available online or on his Warwick homepage.

You’ll have to provide more details about which parts of the proof you don’t understand.

In the first sentence of the proof you swapped the numbers $m$ and $n$. Maybe this is the source of your confusion.

@MoisheKohan Oops thanks for pointing that out. I've since edited this to fix it.

@Deane I'm just confused about how we can find local coordinates $w_{1},...,w_{n}$ at $p$ such that the component functions can be written $y_{i} \circ f = f_{i}(w_{1},...w_{n})$. Why do we know that these local coordinates exist and fulfil the condition that $y_{i} \circ f = f_{i}(w_{1},...w_{n})$ for some local coordinates $y_{i}$.
